# Sample Weighting in regression

Tags: survey, weighted-regression, non-response

I have a survey data with no original instructions on how to do weighting. This survey is voluntary and has been taken by 207 hospitals out of 7000 hospitals in the U.S. There are some characteristics such as teaching status, location, ownership, system membership that I want to weigh my sample on. Except one (No of beds in the hospital), all the other characteristics mentioned above are categorical. How can I do weighting for my sample so that it becomes representative of the population and so that I can adjust for non response bias.

Comment: Do you have data on the distribution of the characteristics in the population of the 7000 hospitals?